# Prove With Vectors That a Parallelogram's Diagonals Bisect

Tags: proof-verification, vectors, plane-geometry

I designed a proof for a problem set but I'm unsure whether the proof is actually conclusive. The proof is as follows:

If a parallelogram's diagonals bisect each other, then...

$\frac{1}{2}(\lvert\vec{A}\rvert + \lvert\vec{B}\rvert) + \frac{1}{2}(\lvert\vec{A}\rvert - \lvert\vec{B}\rvert) - \lvert\vec{A}\rvert = \frac{1}{2}(\lvert\vec{A}\rvert + \lvert\vec{B}\rvert) + \frac{1}{2}(\lvert\vec{B}\rvert - \lvert\vec{A}\rvert) - \lvert\vec{B}\rvert = 0$

With a little algebra, it can be seen that the above equation is true. I'm wondering if there is any way for the equation to be true and not have the diagonals of quadrilateral ABCD (if proof is conclusive, then parallelogram ABCD) bisect.

Comment: Just working with lengths won't prove anything, as far as I can see.

Comment: Where did $\frac12(|\vec A|+|\vec B|)$ come from? Note that the point midway between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is $\frac12(\vec A+\vec B)$, and $|\frac12(\vec A+\vec B)|\neq\frac12(|\vec A|+|\vec B|)$

Comment: `then...` The relation is an algebraic identity, valid for any quadrilateral $\,ABCD\,$.

Comment: The relation isn't even specific to geometric figures. Put any numeric object at all in place of $\lvert\vec{A}\rvert$ and another one in place of $\lvert\vec{B}\rvert.$ You have something of the form $\frac12(p+q)+\frac12(p-q) - p = 0,$ which tells us nothing about the things the equation comes from except that $p$ and $q$ are numbers of a kind that can be added, they have inverses, and it is possible to distribute multiplication by $\frac12$ over them.

Comment: More generally, if you want to prove a statement $P,$ then going around finding facts of the form $P \implies Q$ is likely to be a waste of time. And that's exactly what happened here.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a parallegram, label the corners from lower left, counter clockwise:

A(lower left), B(lower right),C(Upper right),D(Upper left).

Let $AB$ be vector $\vec b$,  $AD$ be vector $\vec a$.

Diagonal $AC$ : $\vec a + \vec b$.

Diagonal $BD$ : $\vec a - \vec b.$

Label the point of intersection of the diagonals $O$.

Consider $\triangle$ $ABO$:

$\alpha (\vec a + \vec b) = \vec b + \beta (\vec a - \vec b), \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Collect coefficients of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$:

$(\alpha - \beta) \vec a + (\alpha + \beta - 1) b = 0$

Since $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are independent (not collinear) it follows that the coefficients of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ must vanish.

1) $\alpha - \beta = 0$, and

2) $\alpha + \beta - 1 = 0.$

Adding and subtracting:

$\alpha = 1/2$,  $\beta = 1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a parallelogram, one diagonal coincident to x-axis and the intersect of two diagonals on origin.
[click here to see the parallelogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrniE.jpg)
One diagonal is divided to be $\vec{a}$ and m$\vec{a}$, the other is $\vec{b}$ and n$\vec{b}$.
$\vec{a}$ + $\vec{l}$ = $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{l}$ + m$\vec{a}$ = n$\vec{b}$
(where m and n are scalars)
$\vec{a}$ - $\vec{b}$ = m$\vec{a}$ - n$\vec{b}$
(m-1)$\vec{a}$ = (n-1)$\vec{b}$
$\vec{a}$=$\begin{pmatrix} |a| \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
$\vec{b}$=$\begin{pmatrix} |b|cos\theta \\ |b|sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$
y direction:
$0=(n-1)|b|sin\theta$
In the parallelogram, $\theta>0$ and $|b|>0$
$\therefore n=1$ and $\vec{b}=n\vec{b}$
diagonal b is bisected.
$\vec{a}=m\vec{a}$
diagonal a is bisected.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: If one vertex of the parallelogram is at the origin and $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are adjacent edges, one diagonal is $\vec A + \vec B$. What is its midpoint? The other diagonal starts, say, at $\vec A$ and proceeds to $\vec B$. What's the vector from the origin to the midpoint of that diagonal?